# How to remove primary clusterset from cluster

Tags: innodb

I want to fully get rid of clusterset in order to switch the single primary into multi primary but I can't get rid of the innodb clusterset from my main primary clusterset!

how should I do it?

I get below error:

```
ERROR: Cannot remove the PRIMARY Cluster of the ClusterSet.
ClusterSet.removeCluster: The Cluster 'SIMIN' is the PRIMARY Cluster of the ClusterSet. (MYSQLSH 51608)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution for this one at oracle document 2899786.1 :)

In order to manually dissolve the primary Cluster, you have to:

- Drop the metadata schema:
  dba.dropMetadataSchema({force: true})

  *** Note: If you get the following error then you need to upgrade to MySQL Shell v.8.0.32 due to Bug 34787737:

  ```
  Dba.dropMetadataSchema: This function is not available through a
  session to an InnoDB Cluster that belongs to an InnoDB ClusterSet (MYSQLSH 51601)
  ```
- Stop GR on all members

  STOP GROUP_REPLICATION;

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/196248)

Answer (score 0):

The primary cluster in an InnoDB ClusterSet cannot be removed using this command. If you do need to remove the primary cluster, you must first carry out a controlled switchover (see Section 8.7, “InnoDB ClusterSet Controlled Switchover”) or an emergency failover (see Section 8.8, “InnoDB ClusterSet Emergency Failover”) to demote the primary cluster to a replica cluster, and promote one of the replica clusters to be the primary cluster. After that, the former primary cluster can be removed using this procedure.

A removed InnoDB Cluster cannot be added back into an InnoDB ClusterSet deployment. If you want to use the server instances in the deployment again, you will need to set up a new cluster using them.